# Problemas con bindValue

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo una duda al usar bindValue, no me vincula el valor de la variable al signo colocado en la consulta. Les dejo el código; espero que puedan ayudarme

```
<?php

    $pdo = new \PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null);

    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
    $error = false;
    $crearTabla = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (`usuario` STRING NULL, `password` STRING NULL,`email` STRING NULL)";
    try{
        $pdo->prepare($crearTabla)->execute();
        echo "Tabla Creada\n";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $insertarUsuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,password,email) VALUES ('Matias','yopassword','matias1588@hotmail.com')";
    try{
        $pdo->prepare($insertarUsuario)->execute();
        echo "Usuario Insertado \n";
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error al insertar el usuario \n".$e->getMessage();
        $error = true;
    }
    if (!$error) {
        $columna = 'usuario';
        $consulta = 'SELECT ? FROM usuarios';
        $stm = $pdo->prepare($consulta);
        $stm->bindValue(1,'usuario', PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $stm->execute();
        $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo "Datos".json_encode($data[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el Manual de PHP no dice esto de forma explícita en ninguna parte, lo cual es un agujero de documentación en el mismo... lo cierto es que **las consultas preparadas son para pasar valores, no para pasar nombres de columnas o de tablas como intentas hacer.**

El motivo es claro: esto no serviría de nada, porque lo que hacen las consultas preparadas es proteger contra la inyección de código a través **de los valores** de las columnas, no a través de los nombres de las mismas. Desde un punto de vista objetivo, esta consulta: `SELECT usuario FROM usuarios` **no tiene ningún peligro** desde el punto de vista de la seguridad.

Si quieres controlar las columnas/tablas que se pueden consultar, lo que puedes hacer es crear una lista blanca de columnas/tablas permitidas y comparar si las mismas están dentro de esa lista, pero no usar consultas preparadas para ello, porque **esa no es su finalidad.**

---

#### Fuentes de referencia

- Por ahora lo que existe es apenas [un comentario en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304) en ingles, refiriéndose a nombres de tabla, pero es válido también para columnas
- Ver también: [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/5587982) en Stackoverflow en inglés

Comment: muchas gracias no habia leido eso saludos